# Sending multipart SMS to many recipients w/Android

Tags: java, android, sms

I am developing a websocket based application that allows me to send SMS with my Android Phone from my PC. 
The communication between server and client is based on the exchange of simple strings containing commands that have to be interpreted from both parts. 
When I send a single part SMS, the client can manage them very good, but when I send a multipart SMS it often freezes, closing the connection with server.

I need to be able to send a big amount of SMS (about 3000 daily).
Here's the code snippet for the routine that allows me to send them.

```
                SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
                ArrayList<String> parts = sms.divideMessage(messaggio);
                ArrayList<PendingIntent> sentPI = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();
                final int parts_size = parts.size();

                registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
                    int msgparts = parts_size;
                    @Override
                    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                        switch (getResultCode())
                        {
                            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                                msgparts--;
                                sent_check_debug = 1;
                                break;
                            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                                msgparts--;
                                sent_check_debug = 2;
                                break;
                            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                                msgparts--;
                                sent_check_debug = 3;
                                break;
                            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                                msgparts--;
                                sent_check_debug = 4;
                                break;
                            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                                msgparts--;
                                sent_check_debug = 5;
                                break;
                        }
                        if(msgparts == 0)
                        {
                            sent_check = 1;
                            if(this != null)
                            unregisterReceiver(this);
                        }
                    }
                }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

                for(int i = 0; i < parts.size(); i++)
                    sentPI.add(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Client.this, 0, new Intent(SENT), 0));

                sms.sendMultipartTextMessage(numero, null, parts, sentPI, null);
                while(sent_check != 1);
```

Where's the error? 
Why after a random numerber of sent messages it freezes?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You're sending the same sentPI for all text messages, so if your code sends `Sms` A with `BroadcastReceiver` A, and then `Sms` B with `BroadcastReceiver` B, receiver B will also get notified on A parts getting sent.

Change the intents you send, and the `IntentFilter` that receive them to be unique per `Sms` you send.

Not sure it causes the freezes, but it might.

Also note that Android has a built-in rate limiter on text messages, it changes from device to device, but users will probably see a warning dialog saying `"This app seems to be sending too many text messages"` or something like that.

EDIT: example code:

```
String msgHash = messaggio.hashCode();
...
registerReceiver(..., new IntentFilter(SENT + "/" + msgHash));

for(int i = 0; i < parts.size(); i++)
    sentPI.add(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Client.this, 0, new Intent(SENT + "/" + msgHash), 0));
```

Now the intent will only trigger its specific BroadcastReceiver, and you could remove the while loop that waits.
It's not a good design to block a thread and wait for a callback to return (or a BroadcastReceiver).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I use the var sent_check to assure that every part of the multipart SMS is sent and the broadcast receiver has captured it all. So it's a sort of waiting for the code.

What you mean for changing Intents but leaving IntentFilter unique per SMS?

Comment: Thank you! I'll try and let you know :-)

Comment: I got the same problem.
After a random number of sent messages it freezes.

I think there's something wrong when the receiver has the Intent back, because the communication between Android and the Server is not lost.

How could I replace that while(sent_check != 1) in a way to let the process know that message is sent?